How to derive a valuation on a locally compact topological field?
I've been studying the concept of a local field, which is defined as follows (can be found from nLab and Wiki):

A local field is a locally compact Hausdorff (non-discrete) topological field.

I came across a statement on nLab that suggest such a field admits a valuation defined by
$$
\|a\| = \frac{\mu(aX)}{\mu(X)},
$$
where $\mu$ is any Haar measure defined on the underlying group, and $0 < \mu(X) < \infty$.
I've checked that $\|\cdot\|$ is well-defined, and:

$\|a\| = 0$ if and only if $a = 0$.
$\|a \cdot b\| = \|a\| \cdot \|b\|$

However, I am stuck on the triangle inequality, i.e.,
$$\mu((a + b)X) \leq \mu(aX) + \mu(bX).$$
Any guidance or references would be appreciated!

You can't prove the triangle inequality because it's wrong if your field is $\Bbb C$
